# SQLite: creating many tables vs. filtering one database for big sets of data

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm wanting to create an activity where you can create folders and within those folders have certain pictures that are associated with them. The way I'm doing it now is by having a database with all the folder names and information linked to a list view. Then I have a SQLite database with all the pictures information that is filtered depending on which list item is clicked.

My dilemma is to create a new table within the database every time a new folder is created or to just have one big database with all the pictures and just filter the pictures I need.

So my question boils down to which method in the long run(with many many pictures and folders) would require the least amount of processing time. Do SQL querys really take up that much time even for big databases? I'm worried if the big database of pictures gets too big the user will have to wait on the query to see the pictures associated with that folder. If I create a table for each folder that is created then the data will be accessible and quick. However would seem harder to maintain and creating tables could be time consuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one large table instead of creating new tables.

You never want to continuously create new tables for every new chunk of data (in this case, folders). This would cause serious performance problems and result in an inflexible database design.

Databases are faster than you expect. Your database probably won't be very large (because it is being stored on a phone), therefore you shouldn't have any difficulty performing simple queries in a short time.